# iptables port forwarding to specify ip

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I use the following command to forward tcp 2222 in a host node to tcp 22 in a vm (192.168.0.100):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.100:22
```

where vmbr0 is a bridge of several public IP addresses in the host node. Now the problem is all public IP addresses in the host node accept incoming requests from tcp 2222. I'm hoping to restrict to only one public IP address. So how should I modify the iptables command to specify the public IP address instead listening on all IP addresses bound to vmbr0?

Answer (score 1):

Got it work by changing `-i` to `-d`:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d x.x.x.x -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.100:22
```

where x.x.x.x is the public IP I want to listening on.